Webpack build creates random files in project directory
Can someone suggest how can I stop creating these files while building the project ?
Issue:
After migrating from AWS SDK v2 to v3, When I ran webpack build for my typescript project for testing locally using AWS SAM, It created multiple files in project directory


OS: Ubuntu22.04
Tech: NodeJs, Typescript, AWS SAM CLI, Webpack-cli
Webpack file
const path = require('path');
const AwsSamPlugin = require('aws-sam-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { EsbuildPlugin } = require('esbuild-loader');

const awsSamPlugin = new AwsSamPlugin({ vscodeDebug: false });

module.exports = {
    entry: () => awsSamPlugin.entry(),
    output: {
        filename: chunkData => awsSamPlugin.filename(chunkData),
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        path: path.resolve('.')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: [
        'sqlite3',
        'pg-query-stream',
        'oracledb',
        'mysql2',
        'mysql',
        'tedious',
        'better-sqlite3',
        'pg'
    ],
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production',
    optimization: {
        minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        minimizer: [
            new EsbuildPlugin({
                target: 'node20'
            })
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                loader: 'esbuild-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: { loader: 'ts', target: 'node20' }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        awsSamPlugin,
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /^pg-native$/ }),
    ],
    ignoreWarnings: [
        {
            message: /Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression/
        }
    ]
};

tsconfig.json file
tsconfig.json file

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "mocha"
    ],
    "module": "ES2015",
    "target": "ES2019",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/src/**/*",
    "./**/test/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules"
  ]
}

